# Elasticsearch / Kibana - How to take point in time snapshot of logs over a particular identifier

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, kibana

What I'm trying to achieve is best explained by example:

I have 4 servers, and each sends a particular log every 12 hours of uptime. The servers are coming up and down for various reasons and so server A may report twice in the time it takes server B to report once, since server B may have been down. Thus, I cannot just use "filter logs of the last 12 hours.

These logs are being stored in Elasticsearch. Each log contains the server name (identifier) that sent the log.

Now, I want to write a query / create a visualization only on: the last log of server A, the last log of server B etc.

So, I can then see things like:

- The last response from each of the servers all returned value V for key K.
- Only 50% of servers as of this point in time (since last reported by each) returned value V1 for key K2.

In other words, I want to see a point in time snapshot of those logs for those servers. I don't really care about the historical logs (in this context), only the last of each.

How would I go about doing such a thing in Kibana? Thanks.

Elasticsearch + Kibana v7.

Comment: The Top Hits aggregation is probably what you are looking for. Their example demonstrates "the last sale", which sounds right on the money to me! https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html

Comment: Hint: terms aggregate on server name field and add top_hit with sorting on timestamp and size : 1 as sub aggregation.